# Assign One User Profile Property to Another SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile

How can I copy the value of one user property to another in SharePoint? We have a custom property called Supervisor which will be entered by the user and I want to copy this property into the Manager field in SharePoint, as the organizational profile is not working without the manager field. I am writing this in PowerShell but it is giving me the following error “Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.” 
My Code is

```
$consultantsupername = $userProfile["ConsultantSupervisor"]
$Managername =$userProfile["Manager"]
$userProfile["Manager"]=$userProfile["ConsultantSupervisor"] 
$userProfile.Commit()
```

Please help me…
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the .Value portion... Check out line 31 of this guy's code:

http://ghamson.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/updating-user-profile-properties-via-powershell-pictureurlsharepoint-2010-in-sp2010/

Comment: Thank you ..That worked beautifully .I have one more question so now i am seeing the change in the manager field but still it is not updating organizational browser .Is there something i am missing????

Comment: Have you synced the User Profile Service?

Comment: Yes i performed an incremental sync ..do i need to perform a full sync ??

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, it might be a Silverlight thing (try clearing the cache?). If that doesn't work, I'd suggest starting a new thread.

Comment: Actually it worked i think we have to wait for 10 min even afer the sync was performed thanks .,..

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.